# How to avoid Daydream re-centering each time I deploy the app during development?

Tags: android, google-vr, daydream

During development I re-deploy the app to the phone frequently. Still, I have a habit of turning off the screen in-between redeployments, otherwise it gets hot inside the Daydream headset.

Each time I turn the phone back on and redeploy the app I re-enter the Daydream-mode and I am forced to re-center the headset.

Here is step-by-step of how I develop:

1. Make changes to the code.
2. Turn the screen on (with on/off button on the phone).
3. Deploy the app.
4. Automatically jump into Daydream-mode.
5. Re-center the headset/controller.
6. Play with the app.
7. Turn off the screen.
8. Repeat.

Can I somehow avoid spending time on re-centering in step 5?

I assume it's not really part of my app, but of the whole Daydream mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Daydream developer setting that will allow you to disable the VR Entry screen (pairing & recentering in the mountains).  Tap the gear icon in the upper right while in VR mode, scroll down to the bottom, tap the Build Version line 7 times.  This will enable a new item for Developer Options.  Go into Developer Options, scroll down near the end of the list to Skip VR entry screens.  Check the box.  No more re-centering on entering VR.  Enjoy your faster development cycles!